# What's the difference between a superblock and an uberblock?

Tags: filesystems, superblock

I'm trying to understand how the different types of blocks work for Unix / Linux file systems.

Where can I find what the difference between a *superblock* and an *uberblock* means?

Comment: One's more über than the other.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I think it was a joke...

Comment: Nevermind the uberblock. What is a 'superblock'?

Comment: Have you done a Google search on the two terms already?  What have you found, and what parts confused you.  Asking questions is good, but it is important to do some basic research yourself as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uber is just German for Super, and is used in English the same way.

You can read about it [here](http://www.linfo.org/superblock.html), let me quote it for you:

> A superblock is a record of the characteristics of a filesystem, including its size, the block size, the empty and the filled blocks and their respective counts, the size and location of the inode tables, the disk block map and usage information, and the size of the block groups.

Uberblock is the Superblock of the ZFS filesystem, here's a [good presentation on ZFS](http://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/pub/Sistemioperativi3/OnLine/ZFSoverview_so3.odp).